# Forest flowchart on beamer slide corner

Tags: beamer, forest, flow-charts

The following forest flowchart was made (spanish language): 
[image]

I want to localize the above flowchart on a small part of beamer's slide:

[image: img2]

I know maybe `\hspace{}` and `\vspace{}` could help, but also something like "resize" is needed. And I don't know how to do it.

Below I copy a MWE with the necessary code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{beamer}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamersize{text margin left=2em,text margin right=2em}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[shrink=25]{Resultados - glioxal}
\medbreak
\centerline{Una vez establecido el estado de protonación se estimó $\Delta G^\circ_{\text{r}}$.}
\vspace{-0.5cm}\centering{
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Reacción problema}\label{table:reaccion_central}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\toprule
             \multicolumn{1}{c}{Compuesto}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{RM1}                      \\ \midrule
                                     & $\Delta G^\circ_{\text{COSMO}}$ & $\Delta G^\circ_{\text{SS-COSMO}}$ \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
CC$_{\text{ref}}$                  &      -                   &    -                         \\ 
cis dihidro-dihidroxi                & 20.6                     & 15.9                        \\ 
trans dihidro-dihidroxi              & 20.6                      & 15.1                         \\ 
&  &  \\ 
H$_{\text{ref}}$                   &    -                      &    -                        \\ 
glioxal-1ºhidratación                & -1.5                    & -4.0                       \\ 
glioxal-2ºhidratación                & -1.4                     & -2.9                       \\ 
glioxal-neta                        & -2.9                     & -6.9                         \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item {\scriptsize $\text{H}_{\text{ref}}$: 2PG = PEP + H2O y $\text{CC}_{\text{ref}}$:2,3-diMMA = propanoato + pir. Se reemplazó dihidro-dihidroxi- imidazol por dihidro-dihidroxi.}%Resultados con hamiltoniano RM1, aplicando la estrategia isodésmica. Las Referencias son:  
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
}\medbreak

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    rounded corners, draw, align=center, top color=white, bottom color=blue!20,
    edge+=->,
    l sep'+=10pt,
  }, 
   [This
     [is the forest
       [chart I want ]%want this block green if is possible.. :)
       [but it is not]
     ]
     [working
       [help!]
     ]
   ] 
\end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`beamer` provides a `columns` environment where you can define as much as columns you need.

In this case you could use three columns, first and third with similar size and second as large as you want. In following code I've used two columns with width equal to `.23\textwidth` and the central one being `.5\textwidth`.

As neither central nor third columns are wide enough for their contents, I've also used a `\resizebox` which scales them to a certain width keeping the aspect ratio of original box.

I don't like the whole design of this slide, but this is another question.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{beamer}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamersize{text margin left=2em,text margin right=2em}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[shrink=25]{Resultados - glioxal}
\begin{columns}[t,onlytextwidth]
\column{.23\textwidth}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\centering
Una vez establecido el estado de protonación se estimó $\Delta G^\circ_{\text{r}}$.

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Reacción problema}\label{table:reaccion_central}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\toprule
             \multicolumn{1}{c}{Compuesto}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{RM1}                      \\ \midrule
                                     & $\Delta G^\circ_{\text{COSMO}}$ & $\Delta G^\circ_{\text{SS-COSMO}}$ \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
CC$_{\text{ref}}$                  &      -                   &    -                         \\ 
cis dihidro-dihidroxi                & 20.6                     & 15.9                        \\ 
trans dihidro-dihidroxi              & 20.6                      & 15.1                         \\ 
&  &  \\ 
H$_{\text{ref}}$                   &    -                      &    -                        \\ 
glioxal-1ºhidratación                & -1.5                    & -4.0                       \\ 
glioxal-2ºhidratación                & -1.4                     & -2.9                       \\ 
glioxal-neta                        & -2.9                     & -6.9                         \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item {\scriptsize $\text{H}_{\text{ref}}$: 2PG = PEP + H2O y $\text{CC}_{\text{ref}}$:2,3-diMMA = propanoato + pir. Se reemplazó dihidro-dihidroxi- imidazol por dihidro-dihidroxi.}%Resultados con hamiltoniano RM1, aplicando la estrategia isodésmica. Las Referencias son:  
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}}
\column[T]{.23\textwidth}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    rounded corners, draw, align=center, top color=white, bottom color=blue!20,
    edge+=->,
    l sep'+=10pt,
  }, 
   [This
     [is the forest
       [chart I want ]%want this block green if is possible.. :)
       [but it is not]
     ]
     [working
       [help!]
     ]
   ] 
\end{forest}}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As @Bobyandbob suggested, you can use `\usepackage{multicol}`, and `\begin{multicols}{2}`right after the centered text (and, of course, `\end{multicols}` right after `\end{frame}`. In order to resize your flowchart, you can use `\scalebox{0.6}{`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{beamer}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamersize{text margin left=2em,text margin right=2em}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[shrink=25]{Resultados - glioxal}
\medbreak
\centerline{Una vez establecido el estado de protonación se estimó         $\Delta G^\circ_{\text{r}}$.}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\vspace{-0.5cm}\centering{
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Reacción problema}\label{table:reaccion_central}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Compuesto}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{RM1}                          \\ \midrule
                                     & $\Delta G^\circ_{\text{COSMO}}$ &     $\Delta G^\circ_{\text{SS-COSMO}}$ \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
CC$_{\text{ref}}$                  &      -                   &    -                         \\ 
cis dihidro-dihidroxi                & 20.6                     & 15.9                        \\ 
trans dihidro-dihidroxi              & 20.6                      & 15.1                             \\ 
&  &  \\ 
H$_{\text{ref}}$                   &    -                      &    -                        \\ 
glioxal-1ºhidratación                & -1.5                    & -4.0                           \\ 
glioxal-2ºhidratación                & -1.4                     & -2.9                           \\ 
glioxal-neta                        & -2.9                     & -6.9                             \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item {\scriptsize $\text{H}_{\text{ref}}$: 2PG = PEP + H2O y     $\text{CC}_{\text{ref}}$:2,3-diMMA = propanoato + pir. Se reemplazó     dihidro-dihidroxi- imidazol por dihidro-dihidroxi.}%Resultados con     hamiltoniano RM1, aplicando la estrategia isodésmica. Las Referencias son:  
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
}\medbreak

\scalebox{0.6}{
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    rounded corners, draw, align=center, top color=white, bottom     color=blue!20,
    edge+=->,
    l sep'+=10pt,
  }, 
   [This
     [is the forest
       [chart I want ]%want this block green if is possible.. :)
       [but it is not]
     ]
     [working
       [help!]
     ]
   ] 
\end{forest}
}
\end{multicols}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is quite good, but I need the table to remain on the center..

Comment: @Schopenhauer: you could use 3 columns: the _first_ one empty (see how to do this here: tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8683/…), the _central_ one larger than the 1st and 3rd (in order to accommodate the table), and the _third_ one (with the same width than the 1st one, in order to keep de 2nd column centralized) with the flowchart.