# Make beamer center only table of both table and flowchart

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, forest, flow-charts

I am trying to center only a table in a slide where there is a table and a forest flowchart. I have made a similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398567/how-to-center-only-one-graph) but don't know why is not working on this slide. Below I provide an image of this problem and then a minimal working example.

[image: problemimage]

Here is a **MWE**:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
%\documentclass[handout, hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\let\Tiny=\tiny
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{marvosym}
%\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usecolortheme{whale} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}  
\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{} 
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamersize{text margin left=2em,text margin right=2em}

\addtolength{\columnsep}{2cm}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{float}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[shrink=15]{Resultados - Método de solvatación}
\begin{itemize}
\item Here some text...
\end{itemize}

\vspace{0cm}\mbox{}\hfill\scalebox{0.50}{
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    rounded corners, draw, align=center, top color=white, bottom color=blue!30,
    edge+=->,
    l sep'+=10pt,
  }, 
   [Solvatación
     [Explícito+Implícito
       [SS/COSMO, bottom color=green!30]%want this block green
       [Packmol/COSMO, bottom color=gray!30]
     ]
%     [Implícito
%       [COSMO]
%     ]
   ] 
\end{forest}
}\hspace{-4cm}
\vspace{-0.5cm}\centering{
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Convergence RM1 - DHAP}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}\toprule
nºconf & $\Delta G^\circ_{\text{f(SS)}}$ & $\Delta G^\circ_{\text{f(Packmol)}}$ & $\sigma_{\text{SS}}$ & $\sigma_{\text{Packmol}}$ \\  \midrule
5 & -1756.3 & -1758.4 & 1.2 & 3.8 \\  
10 & -1754.6 & -1760.8 & 2.9 & 1.3 \\  
15 & -1755.7 & -1761.3 & 1.9 & 0.9 \\  
20 & -1757.2 & -1761.6 & 0.3 & 0.5 \\  
30 & -1757.2 & -1764.2 & 0.3 & -2.0 \\  
50 & -1757.5 & -1762.1 & - & - \\ 
\textbf{MAE} &  &  & 1.3 & 1.7 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item {Here some text as a note..}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}}
\centerline{ And short a conclusion like this...}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Would you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shrink` has the unfortunate side effect, that it decreases the available horizontal space. So I suggest to either change the layout of the slide (maybe the tree could fit besides the table?) or use a smaller font size.

And please do not use `\centerline`.

**Smaller fontsize:**

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
%\documentclass[handout, hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\let\Tiny=\tiny
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{marvosym}
%\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usecolortheme{whale} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}  
\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{} 
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamersize{text margin left=2em,text margin right=2em}

\addtolength{\columnsep}{2cm}

%\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{forest}
%\usepackage{float}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
%\floatstyle{plaintop}
%\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Resultados - Método de solvatación}
\fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\selectfont
\begin{itemize}
\item Here some text...
\end{itemize}
\centering

\hfill\scalebox{0.50}{
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    rounded corners, draw, align=center, top color=white, bottom color=blue!30,
    edge+=->,
    l sep'+=10pt,
  }, 
   [Solvatación
     [Explícito+Implícito
       [SS/COSMO, bottom color=green!30]%want this block green
       [Packmol/COSMO, bottom color=gray!30]
     ]
%     [Implícito
%       [COSMO]
%     ]
   ] 
\end{forest}
}

\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Convergence RM1 - DHAP}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}\toprule
nºconf & $\Delta G^\circ_{\text{f(SS)}}$ & $\Delta G^\circ_{\text{f(Packmol)}}$ & $\sigma_{\text{SS}}$ & $\sigma_{\text{Packmol}}$ \\  \midrule
5 & -1756.3 & -1758.4 & 1.2 & 3.8 \\  
10 & -1754.6 & -1760.8 & 2.9 & 1.3 \\  
15 & -1755.7 & -1761.3 & 1.9 & 0.9 \\  
20 & -1757.2 & -1761.6 & 0.3 & 0.5 \\  
30 & -1757.2 & -1764.2 & 0.3 & -2.0 \\  
50 & -1757.5 & -1762.1 & - & - \\ 
\textbf{MAE} &  &  & 1.3 & 1.7 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item {Here some text as a note..}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

centering And short a conclusion like this...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Different layout:**

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
%\documentclass[handout, hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\let\Tiny=\tiny
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{marvosym}
%\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usecolortheme{whale} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}  
\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{} 
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamersize{text margin left=2em,text margin right=2em}

\addtolength{\columnsep}{2cm}

%\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{forest}
%\usepackage{float}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
%\floatstyle{plaintop}
%\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Resultados - Método de solvatación}

\begin{itemize}
\item Here some text...
\end{itemize}

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{.65\textwidth}
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \caption{Convergence RM1 - DHAP}
            \begin{tabular}{ccccc}\toprule
                nºconf & $\Delta G^\circ_{\text{f(SS)}}$ & $\Delta G^\circ_{\text{f(Packmol)}}$ & $\sigma_{\text{SS}}$ & $\sigma_{\text{Packmol}}$ \\  \midrule
                5 & -1756.3 & -1758.4 & 1.2 & 3.8 \\  
                10 & -1754.6 & -1760.8 & 2.9 & 1.3 \\  
                15 & -1755.7 & -1761.3 & 1.9 & 0.9 \\  
                20 & -1757.2 & -1761.6 & 0.3 & 0.5 \\  
                30 & -1757.2 & -1764.2 & 0.3 & -2.0 \\  
                50 & -1757.5 & -1762.1 & - & - \\ 
                \textbf{MAE} &  &  & 1.3 & 1.7 \\ \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tablenotes}
                \footnotesize
                \item{Here some text as a note..}
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
        \scalebox{0.73}{
            \begin{forest}
              for tree={
                rounded corners, draw, align=center, top color=white, bottom color=blue!30,
                edge+=->,
                l sep'+=10pt,
              }, 
               [Solvatación
                 [Explícito+Implícito
                   [SS/COSMO, bottom color=green!30]%want this block green
                   [Packmol/COSMO, bottom color=gray!30]
                 ]
            %     [Implícito
            %       [COSMO]
            %     ]
               ] 
            \end{forest}
        }
    \end{column}
\end{columns}

\begin{center}
    And short a conclusion like this...
\end{center}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks sam, I was aware about side effects..\\Yes, besides the table would be good anyway. I will make the changes to some other slides also and see how it looks. Thanks again!

Comment: @Schopenhauer please see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/311294/36296

Comment: The second is good but need the table centered..maybe is not possible with columns

Comment: Is it possible to move the flowchart on the first case a bit down? I have tried with `\vspace{}` but it moves also the table..

Comment: @Schopenhauer Alex already told you how to do this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398418/forest-flowchart-on-beamer-slide-corner#comment991592_398546

Comment: I am sorry to bother but alex answer has been edited and doesn't work (I can be mistaken). Try it, the table is not centered.

Comment: @Schopenhauer The answer has never been edited and I did not link to the answer but to the comment below: short summary: If you want my second answer to be centred, use three columns instead of two (you will have to adjust the widths to be still < 1 in sum).

Comment: Good..I will try that..